# Unsolved Error during Docker installation

Tags: python, docker

i have a problem while trying to install Docker on my computer.
I am following this tutorial : https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/

But when I get to step 3 and i try this command :  sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop--.deb with version : 4.16.2 and arch : amd64 i have this problem :

" E: Unsupported file ./docker-desktop-4.16.2-amd64.deb given on commandline ".

I tried to check on google if someone had the same problem once but i didn't find out anything.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Move your downloaded file to the home directory, then run the command again in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file to your Home directory and run `sudo dpkg -i docker-desktop-4.16.2-amd64` && `sudo apt install -f` after installing  docker-ce-cli and uidmap on my case